# SharePoint search refiners are visible only for Site collection administrators

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2013, 2016, search-results, refinement-panel

We have a SharePoint search results page and it has a refiners webpart

It only has "Created" property as a refiner, but it is visible only to Site collection administrators

When other users search, they only see the search results and the refiners are not appearing

It does not have any target audiences too.

Not sure why it is not appearing for other users, any advice is appreciated

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue per my test, the user with edit permission can see newly added refiner successfully.

Create a new search center, add the **Created** column as refiner, compare the result.